# Concatenating variable for the ID value in xpath-selenium Webdriver

Tags: java

My xpath is //*[@id='u2001']
It contains value 2001, but i dont want to use direct xpath instead i want to make the value 2001 alone as my input into the xpath, 
say for example something like .//*[@id='u**currentYearminus15**']
here currentYearminus15 is my variable declared

Can someone help me how can insert my variable declared in the ID value?
I want to know the syntax of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your need is only Java coding.
Declare 'currentYearminus15' as a String variable.

```
String s = "currentYearminus15";
```

Give your Xpath as `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='u"+s+"']"));`

Comment: Thank you so much. The above code is working for me. This is what i was expecting

Comment: @Meghasri Its fine and if the answer met your requirement can you please accept the answer by ticking it.